# SQL missing indexes from select Databases

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

I am trying to use the SQL missing index feature; however.... I am not the DBO or admin. I have access to one database. is there a way to run this for only a single database without elevated permission

```
SELECT 

  migs.avg_total_user_cost * (migs.avg_user_impact / 100.0) * (migs.user_seeks + migs.user_scans) AS improvement_measure, 

  'CREATE INDEX [missing_index_' + CONVERT (varchar, mig.index_group_handle) + '_' + CONVERT (varchar, mid.index_handle) 

  + '_' + LEFT (PARSENAME(mid.statement, 1), 32) + ']'

  + ' ON ' + mid.statement 

  + ' (' + ISNULL (mid.equality_columns,'') 

    + CASE WHEN mid.equality_columns IS NOT NULL AND mid.inequality_columns IS NOT NULL THEN ',' ELSE '' END 

    + ISNULL (mid.inequality_columns, '')

  + ')' 

  + ISNULL (' INCLUDE (' + mid.included_columns + ')', '') AS create_index_statement, 

  migs.*, mid.database_id, mid.[object_id]

FROM sys.dm_db_missing_index_groups mig

INNER JOIN sys.dm_db_missing_index_group_stats migs ON migs.group_handle = mig.index_group_handle

INNER JOIN sys.dm_db_missing_index_details mid ON mig.index_handle = mid.index_handle

WHERE migs.avg_total_user_cost * (migs.avg_user_impact / 100.0) * (migs.user_seeks + migs.user_scans) > 10

ORDER BY migs.avg_total_user_cost * migs.avg_user_impact * (migs.user_seeks + migs.user_scans) DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

[**`dm_db_missing_index_details`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms345434.aspx) dynamic view has `Database Id` in it.

```
WHERE  migs.avg_total_user_cost * ( migs.avg_user_impact / 100.0 ) * ( migs.user_seeks + migs.user_scans ) > 10
       AND mid.database_ID = Db_id('Database name') --Here
```

**Note :** `Users` must be granted the `VIEW SERVER STATE` permission or any permission that implies the `VIEW SERVER STATE` permission to access all the three dynamic view used in your query

Comment: sounds like there is not way to get this to work without contacting IT and requesting permissions?

Answer (score 1):

Add following in the where clause:

```
AND mid.database_ID = Db_id('Your Database name')
```